# Was "Cuán(to)..." always synonymous with "Qué tan(to)..."?

Tags: historia, palabras-interrogativas

In many dialects of Latin American Spanish *Qué tan(to)...* is used in interrogative/exclamative phrases with the same meaning as the *Cuán(to)...* (or *Cómo de...*).

Indeed, this phrase was used in Spain with some frequency up until the 17th century.

**Question:** Was *cuán(to)* always used in this context in Spanish, alongside *qué tan(to)*, or did it only acquire this use later on as *qué tan(to)* was declining in popularity in Spain?

---

<sup>**1.** [DAMER: tanto](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tanto)</sup>  <sup>I.e) `ǁ ¿qué ~?`</sup>
<sup>**2.** [DLE: tanto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z60aNMi)</sup>  <sup>`qué tan, o qué tanto`</sup>
<sup>**3.** [DPD: qué](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=qu%C3%A9)</sup>  <sup>`4.(g) qué tan(to).`</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I cannot fully endorse that its popularity has been declining; however, I can confirm that they can be used interchangeably.

Although, I prefer using *¿Cuánto...* to *¿Qué tanto....* depending on the case. Namely, I would say,

> —¿Cuánto dinero necesitas?
>   —¿Cuánto la amas?
>   —¿Cuánto tiempo estuviste ahí?

but I wouldn't replace *cuánto* by *qué tanto* in these cases. And yet, its use hinges profoundly upon the region you are, meaning that it may sound idiomatic for some, but not for others.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `"declining in popularity [in *Spain*]"` - have clarified that phrase in the question now.

Comment: Is the usage in "Qué tanto por ciento" different? See the answer to https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30542/11155.