# "Cuánto por ciento" or "Cuántos por ciento"?

Tags: plurales, números

How to correctly ask about the percentage? 
Is *por ciento* handled as *singular* or as *plural*?

Comment: It would be singular if you're asking about one statistic, and plural if you're asking about more than one, e.g. *What are the percentages of passing grades and superior grades? ¿Cuáles son los porcentajes de resultados aceptables y resultados excelentes?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use *por ciento* to ask, you use *[porcentaje](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TgZN1sz)*:

> ¿Qué porcentaje de alumnos son niños?
>   ¿Cuáles son los porcentajes de nitrógeno y oxígeno en el aire?
>   ¿Cuánto porcentaje de grasa tienen las salchichas?

Or *[tanto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Z60aNMi) por ciento* (see 12th entry in the dictionary):

> ¿Qué tanto por ciento de sal debería haber en la receta del pan?

Comment: Is there a general rule where you use "qué tanto" and where "cuánto(s)"?

Comment: @HonzaZidek that's probably a regional thing, as I almost never use "qué tanto" (I'm from Spain), but in other countries it is probably more used. You should ask a separate question if you are interested.

Comment: Done, see https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30545/11155

Comment: @walen Thanks for your note, I did not know it, since I am aware of the fact that "Qué tanto" is used instead of "Cuánto(s)" sometimes.